# Javascript: Replace a Shown Div with another Hidden Div with Button onclick

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i want to replace a div that is already displayed with another Hidden div with just one click. i don't want it to toggle. below is the code.

```
<html>

<script type="text/javascript">
function show(elementId) { 
 document.getElementById("surf").style.display="none";
 document.getElementById(elementId).style.display="block";
}
</script>

<div id="mode" style="display: visible;">Display By Default</div>

<div id="surf" style="display: none;">Display On Click</div>
<br/>
<button type="submit" id="submit" onclick="show('surf');" name="submit">Submit</button>
</html>
```

My desired output should be `Display On Click` when i click the button.

But right now i'm having both `Display By Default` and `Display On Click` showing when i click the button `display by default` at the top and `Display On Click` at button. i just want `Display By Default` to be replaced with `Display On Click` on same line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <body>
    <div id="div1" style="display:block">
    <h2>first div</h2>
</div>
<div id="div2" style="display:none">
    <h2>second div</h2>
</div>
<button onclick=show()>click here</button>
</body>
<script>
function show() {
    let div1 = document.querySelector('#div1');
    let div2 = document.querySelector('#div2');

    if (div1.style.display == "block") {
        div1.style.display = "none";
        div2.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        div1.style.display = "block";
        div2.style.display = "none";
    }

  }
</script>
</html>
```

onclick to hide div1 and show div2,
Next click hide div2 and show div1.

Comment: appreciate your work thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You are targeting the wrong element here `document.getElementById("surf").style.display="none";`. The `"surf"` should be `"mode"` instead. This worked for me

```js
function show(elementId) { 
    document.getElementById("mode").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById(elementId).style.display="block";
}
```

```html
<div id="mode" style="display: visible;">Display By Default</div>
<div id="surf" style="display: none;">Display On Click</div>
<br/>
<button type="submit" id="submit" onclick="show('surf');" name="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: it Worked, guess i didn't notice that little error, Thank you @ruleboy21 <3